# Why are my settlers not doing their jobs and refusing to stay assigned?

Tags: fallout-4

One day I went back to my settlement and everyone was unassigned, I was fine with that, just a little glitch I have no problem reassigning 30 settlers. The problem is when I try, It says they are still unassigned. sometimes it works after 10 minutes of fiddling, but they become unassigned a minute after.

Does anyone know if this is a glitch and if there is some way to fix it? I would really appreciate it, especially, according to my save files I have played for 3 days in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my cache was full and needed to empty it, it also helped to delete all my old save files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a crash a lot of times when all setllers in the settlement became completely unassigned. It happen during different actions so I have no answer what really action made the crashing. Couple of times happened when I tried to assign settlers not to the work but to the bed because during the night they just stayed as zombies
I know it is the bug and there is nothing to do with it - just reassing / start new game / try to load the save before...
As I understood there was no 100% cure for it.
The one thing that could help is to make fast assigning of the settlers again as:
* The tape for computer to work with if you will install the mod "Settlement management software" or similar.
* Building of Vault-Tec Population Management System if you will buy Fallout 4 additional DLC "Vault-Tec Workshop".

If the problem still exist there are classic general rules for Fallout 4 to eliminate problems - get out of the settlement and return again / sleep 1 hour / save the new game and try to reaload it / reload the game before bug appeared